# Content-Disposition not returning filename

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, content-disposition

I have been trying to upload a file to a folder in my server, but I need the file Name. I followed this tutorial (http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-file-upload-example-with-servlet-30-api). But I can't get the Filename that I've been uploading. The content of my "content-disposition" :

> form-data; name="id"

I've already added the enctype to the form, and the annotation to the Servlet .Could you give me some help? Thank you

Comment: Please provide us code of your servlet. Without it, it is hard to help you.